# How can I link two fragments with Android Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using [Android Jetpack's Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) with a [bottom navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation), like this:

[image: Navigation graph: "mobile_navigation.xml"]

[image: Bottom navigation bar: "BottomNavigationView"]

Let's focus on Home and Dashboard destinations, Dashboard displays a list of departments, each department displays a list of products, and each product displays a detailed description. So far everything works fine.

However, **Home should displays the full list of products directly**, and here is the question: how can I display the `product_list` fragment directly on Home when the application is started (and every time Home is accessed)?

Note that I can't put the `product_list` code directly into Home fragment, because then the navigation from Dashboard would go to Home.

Also, if I put `findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.nextAction())` on the Home fragment `onCreateView(...)`, every time I go to Home it displays the list of products, but also the *Up* button on the app bar, which is not going anywhere (it goes to Home which redirects to `product_list` again).

[image: App action bar: "Toolbar"]

I only need the *Up* button when accessing the `product_list` through the department list on Dashboard. The `product_list` should be displayed on Home as if it were the Home itself.

So, I'm looking for a way to directly link these two fragments, without any transactions, or by avoiding the *Up* button on the app bar (perhaps by avoiding adding the transaction to the transaction back stack).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="cu.lcnicolau.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/next_action"
            app:destination="@id/product_list">
            <argument
                android:name="departmentId"
                android:defaultValue="0" />
        </action>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_departments"
        android:name="cu.lcnicolau.ui.departments.DepartmentsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_departments"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_departments">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/next_action"
            app:destination="@id/product_list" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/product_list"
        android:name="cu.lcnicolau.ui.products.ItemListFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/next_action"
            app:destination="@id/product_detail" />
        <argument
            android:name="departmentId"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/product_detail"
        android:name="cu.lcnicolau.ui.products.ItemDetailFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_product_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_detail">
        <argument
            android:name="item"
            app:argType="cu.lcnicolau.dummy.Product" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Comment: what if you just make the same logic and similar layout in Home and Product  List

Comment: @eto: [**D**on't **r**epeat **y**ourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

This way might meet your needs:

**1. Setup the `bottom_nav`**

1. Create global action that can be used from anywhere within the navigation graph. `DepartmentsFragment` will use this to navigate to `ItemListFragment`.
2. Create action inside `navigation_home`. The important property here is `app:popUpTo="@+id/bottom_nav` (your graph id), it will remove HomeFragment from backstack and affected to BottomNavigationView when onBackPressed being called from other fragment. We will make the ActivityCallback to resolve this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">
    
    <action
        android:id="@+id/to_product_list"
        app:destination="@id/product_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home" android:name="com.example.stackoverflowhelps.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/home_to_product_list"
            app:destination="@id/product_list"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/bottom_nav" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/product_list" android:name="com.example.stackoverflowhelps.ui.products.ProductsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_products" >
         <argument
            android:name="departmentId"
            app:argType="long" />
    </fragment>
    
    ...
</navigation>
```

3. Call global action from `DepartmentsFragment`

```js
findNavController().navigate(toProductList(departementId))
```

4. Anywhere in the initial callback of `HomeFragment`

```js
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   findNavController().navigate(homeToProductList(-1))
}
```

---

**2. Setup MainActivity and NavCallback**

The purpose of this callback is to navigate BottomNavigationView to Home when onBackPressed from two other bottom menu. Since we lost HomeFragment in the backstack every we enter ItemListFragment from Home.

1. `NavCallback.java`

   ```js
   interface NavCallback {
       enum class Nav { HOME, DASHBOARD, OFFERS }

       fun navigateToMenu(nav: Nav)
   }
   ```
2. `MainActivity.java`

   ```js
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavCallback {

       private lateinit var navView: BottomNavigationView

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
           navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

           val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
           
           // optional: if you want to permanently remove default ActionBar BackButton from ItemListFragment, add product_list navigation id to appBarConfiguration
           val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
               setOf(
                   R.id.navigation_home,
                   R.id.navigation_dashboard,
                   R.id.navigation_offers,
                   R.id.product_list
               )
           )
           setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
           navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
       }

       override fun navigateToMenu(nav: NavCallback.Nav) {
           val dest: Int = when(nav) {
               NavCallback.Nav.HOME -> R.id.navigation_home
               NavCallback.Nav.DASHBOARD -> R.id.navigation_home
               NavCallback.Nav.OFFERS -> R.id.navigation_notifications
           }

           navView.selectedItemId = dest
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the `NavCallback` when overriding onBackPressed inside `DepartmentsFragment` and `OffersFragment`. We will manually select bottom nav menu to Home, see `NavCallback.Nav.HOME`

```js
class DepartmentsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var navCallback: NavCallback? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                navCallback?.navigateToMenu(NavCallback.Nav.HOME)
            }
        }
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, callback)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            navCallback = context as NavCallback
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            activity.toString() + " must implements NavCallback"
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        navCallback = null
        super.onDetach()
    }


    ...
}
```

Until here, we have got the desired UI flow.

---

**3. Determine the Product List data and the visibility of Back Button in the `ItemListFragment`**

I prefer to use custom toolbar view and back button for convenience reasons. At this time we will use argument `departmentId` to determine the visibility of back button

```js
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
   val departmentId: Long = arguments?.getLong("departmentId") ?: 0
   if (departmentId > 0) {
       textView.text = departmentId.toString()
       back.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       back.setOnClickListener { requireActivity().onBackPressed() }
            
       // from fetch the data with given id 
    } else {
      back.visibility = View.GONE
      // come from HomeFragment, fetch all data
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use NoActionBar theme for MainActivity, and remove `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)` from your MainActivity. You need to use your own appbar/toolbar inside fragment layout.

Comment: You may prefer to use specific argument (boolean) passed to ItemListFragment to define whether it was called from HomeFragment or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like this approach because it negates the [Android Jetpack's Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) patterns, forcing the developer to deal with the behavior of the bottom navigation and the app bar.

Comment: For the backPressedDispatcher you can use the ktx extension: `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) { navCallback?.navigateToMenu(NavCallback.Nav.HOME) }
`